# why 'if 'construct is not running in this C code?

Tags: c, if-statement, string.h

**i have entered 'pass1' as a value to 'str' so that 'if' construct would work but still its not working.
code is down below:**

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ab "pass1"

int main() {
  char pass[8];
  char str[8];
  printf("Enter a string :");
  gets(str);
  strcpy(pass, str);

  printf("your string is %s ", str);

  if (pass == ab) {
    printf("la swagat cha!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==`. You need a function like `strcmp()`.

Comment: Aside, [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).